# replace multiple blanks with one blank in C

Tags: c, replace, space

I'm writing some simple c programming code to replace a string of multiple blanks with a single blank. my code is as follows but it obviously contains errors. I'm trying to avoid the use of array or pointers. So any advice on how to correct my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c,d;
    d=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
        if (c==' ')
            {
                d=getchar();
                if (d!=' '&&d!=EOF)
                    putchar(c);
            }
        putchar(c);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First: avoid useing `getchar`, `putchar`. Use `getc`, `putc` instead.

If you badly want to read character by character then something like this would do:

```
int c, lastc = '\0';
while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' && lastc == ' ')
        continue;
    putc(c, stdout);
    lastc = c;
}
```

Comment: Where is it said that `getchar` and `putchar` are deprecated? I see no indication of that in 7.21.7.6 or 7.21.7.8 of N1570.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, confused them with `gets` which is indeed deprecated. Removed that part.

Comment: I see. `gets` is not only deprecated, it has been _removed_, oh joy!

Comment: `lastc` may be used uninitialized. And, please, Insert `continue;` in a new line.

Answer (score 3):

When doing this kind of filtering, it's often a good idea to never repeat the reading of input, since that tends to scatter the logic. At least in my experience, I find it easier if I read input in *one* place and then deal with it.

For this problem, a simple state machine is enough: just remember if the last character was blank or not, and only output blanks if the last character read was not a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to remember if you've read a blank or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int lastBlank = 0;
  int c;

  while ( (c = fgetc( stdin )) != EOF )
  {
    if ( c != ' ' || !lastBlank )
      fputc( c, stdout );

    lastBlank = ( c == ' ' );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*copy input to output, replacing each 
string of one or more blanks by a single blank.*/

main() {

    int c;

    while((c =getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c!= ' ') 
            putchar(c);
        else {
            putchar(c);
            while((c =getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation:
- First while loop checks if there is no EOF and continues the operation
- Then, "if" statement  checks if there is no blank character is present and prints character from the input stream
- Once blank character is detected, it goes in else condition, then without doing anything it prints the first blank space
- Then if there are more than one blank space, it goes into while loop and do nothing until end of blank spaces
- When there are no blank spaces, it goes out and print the next character present in the stream

Answer (score 1):

```
 main()
 {
     int c, d;
     d = 0;
     
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
         if (c == ' ' && d == ' ') {
            ;
         }
         else {
            putchar(c);
         }
         
         was_blank = c;
    }
 }
```

**Caveat**, this doesn't count tabs as "more than one blank".

This is the output on an `ls -la /` command:

```
total 88
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 4 21:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 4 21:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 21 14:52 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:56 boot
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:57 .cache
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:57 .config
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 3300 Oct 6 17:30 dev
drwxr-xr-x 145 root root 12288 Oct 6 17:30 etc
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 80 Oct 6 17:30 .fehbg
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:55 home
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 21 14:52 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 21 14:52 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 21 14:52 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Sep 4 20:51 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 21 14:52 media
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:56 mnt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 21 15:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 255 root root 0 Oct 6 17:29 proc
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep 4 21:12 pulse
drwx------ 7 root root 4096 Sep 4 20:51 root
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 1100 Oct 6 17:31 run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 21 14:52 sbin -> usr/sbin
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Oct 6 17:29 sys
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4096 Oct 6 17:51 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Aug 21 14:52 usr
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Aug 21 15:01 var
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, d;
    d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            while ((d = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(c);
            putchar(d);
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int nextChar(FILE *fp){
    static int buff = 0;
    int ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(buff != ch)
        buff = ch;
    else
        while(buff == ' ')
            buff = fgetc(fp);
    return buff;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    int ch;
    while(EOF!=(ch=nextChar(fp))){
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int c , n;
    n=0;

    while((c=getchar())!= EOF) {
        if (c == '\t') {

            if (n<1){
                putchar('\t');
                n=n+1;
            }
        }
        else {
            n=0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        if (c == ' ') {
            // if we found a blank continue reading
            // searching for additional blanks
            // put one blank char to output stream
            // put the char that casue the while loop to exit
            while((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing with a simple file containing varying numbers of blanks produces the correct behavior

```
➜  course-c cat data
one space two  spaces three   spaces four   spaces five     spaces


➜  course-c ./replace.blank < data
one space two spaces three spaces four spaces five spaces
```